# Using CreateChatRequest occurs Not enough users (to create a chat, for example)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

`telethon` vaersion: 0.19.1.4

`Python version` : 3.6.

When using `CreateChatRequest` to create a group, it occurs error like this:

```
CreateChatRequest occurs Not enough users (to create a chat, for example).
```

And my code like this:

```
user = InputUser(user_id=12345, access_hash=12345678901234)
client(CreateChatRequest([user], title=title))
```

`user_id` and `access_hash` is correct, but I'm confused about the error message.

Comment: You have to invite another user

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, as well, even when I tried to supply 2 or 3 users in the initial user list.  In the end I figured out the problem: the users weren't letting me add them to the group since I wasn't in their contacts, and their privacy settings did not allow such things. I was able to create the group using just one user whose permissions allowed me to add them.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create a new group, you can use `CreateChannelRequest` method and set  `megagroup=True`

also, if you want to add a user to the group you can use `InviteToChannelRequest` method

```
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest, 
CreateChannelRequest

group=client(CreateChannelRequest(title='test group',about='this is test group',megagroup=True))

print('group created')

# add a user to the group
custom_user='Shahabi77' # username
user_entity=client.get_entity(custom_user)
client(InviteToChannelRequest(
group.chats[0],
[user_entity]
))

print('user added & finish')
```

Comment: The OP was asking about group chats, not megagroups. There are a number of differences between the two